# curl: (28) Failed to connect to dist.ipfs.io port 443: Operation timed out

Tags: ipfs

I am trying to install ipfs using the following command from this link

[enter link description here](https://docs.ipfs.io/install/command-line/#official-distributions)

```
curl -O https://dist.ipfs.io/go-ipfs/v0.9.1/go-ipfs_v0.9.1_darwin-arm64.tar.gz
```

but every time when I run it on terminal gives me this error

> curl: (28) Failed to connect to dist.ipfs.io port 443: Operation timed
> out

I am using MacBook m1 chip.
also I am using VPN for google services.

Comment: Working fine for me, is this still an issue? It's possible we had issues with a cert back when this was asked...